# Trigonometry: Find the value of $x$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I have been given this triangle and I am asked to find the value of $x$.

I'm not able to understand few things-

1) Is it a valid triangle? (Three angles could be $180^{\circ}$.)

2) How would I find $x$?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Yes this is a "valid triangle".
$$
\angle A = \angle B = 80^\circ, \quad \angle C=20^\circ.
$$

(2) Choose the scale: let $AB=1$. Let point $D\in AC$, $\angle ABD=60^\circ$.
Let point $E\in BC$, $\angle BAE=70^\circ$. So $x = \angle AED$.

We can find $AD$ and $AE$, by applying the law of sines to triangles $ABD$ and $ABE$:
$$
{AD\over\sin60^\circ} = {AB\over\sin40^\circ}, \quad
AD={AB\cdot\sin60^\circ\over\sin40^\circ}
\approx{0.8660253\over0.6427876} \approx 1.347296,
$$
$$
{AE\over\sin80^\circ} = {AB\over\sin30^\circ}, \quad
AE={AB\cdot\sin80^\circ\over\sin30^\circ}
\approx{0.98480775\over0.5} \approx 1.9696155.
$$
Now we can find $DE$ using coordinates. Assume $A$ is the origin, 
$x_A=y_A=0$, then
$$
x_D=AD\cos80^\circ\approx0.233955, \quad y_D=AD\sin80^\circ\approx1.3268275,
$$
$$
x_E=AE\cos70^\circ\approx0.673648, \quad y_E=AE\sin70^\circ\approx1.8508331,
$$
$$
DE=\sqrt{(x_E-x_D)^2+(y_E-y_D)^2}\approx\sqrt{0.439693^2+0.524006^2}
=0.684041\ldots
$$
Finally, we find $x$ by applying the law of sines to triangle $ADE$:
$$
{AD\over\sin x} = {DE\over\sin 10^\circ}, \quad
\sin x = {AD\cdot\sin10^\circ\over DE} \approx 0.342020,
$$
$$
x = \arcsin(0.342020) \approx 20^\circ.
$$

Comment: we assumed AB=1.. I guess Sine law wouldn't have applied if we didn't have assumed AB=1?.. (Why did we assume it to be 1 in the first place?)

Comment: @TechnoCorner We did not **have to** assume $AB=1$. (We did so simply to shorten the formulas.) Alternatively, we could keep writing $AB$ where applicable, and it would cancel out at the end. The law of sines would still apply. For example, when determining $AD$ we would get $$AD=AB\cdot\sin60^\circ/\sin40^\circ\approx1.347296\cdot AB,$$ and so on.